# JavaScript space-separated string to camelCase

Tags: javascript, camelcasing, sentencecase

I've seen plenty of easy ways to convert `camelCaseNames` to `camel Case Names`, etc. but none on how to convert `Sentence case names` to `sentenceCaseNames`. Is there any easy way to do this in JS?

Comment: Sure, toLowerCase, split on space, concatenate after uppercasing the first letter.

Comment: What have you tried?  Split on space, then change lettering, then concatenate.

Comment: I'm not sure my browser can keep up with the up and down votes!

Comment: @showdev no, that's the other way around

Comment: @Supuhstar Am I missing something? You want `Sentence case names to sentenceCaseNames`, right? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970525/javascript-regex-camel-case-sentence-case#answer-2970667) does `Equipment Class Name to equipmentClassName`.

Comment: It is a duplicate, despite its misleading title. The two answers have the same result: http://jsfiddle.net/Uz7Te/

Comment: @showdev thanks... gawsh this isn't the first time I've been fooled by a terrible title either :/

Comment: I know, same here. Also, I don't mean to diminish ShaneQful's answer -- it works well and is arguably cleaner code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
function toCamelCase(sentenceCase) {
    var out = "";
    sentenceCase.split(" ").forEach(function (el, idx) {
        var add = el.toLowerCase();
        out += (idx === 0 ? add : add[0].toUpperCase() + add.slice(1));
    });
    return out;
}
```

Explanation:

- `sentenceCase.split(" ")` creates and array out of the sentence eg. ["Sentence", "case", "names"]
- `forEach` loops through each variable in the array
- inside the loop each string is lowercased, then the first letter is uppercased(apart for the first string) and the new string is appended to the `out` variable which is what the function will eventually return as the result.

Comment: Thank you. It seems you're the only one who understands my question XD

Comment: @ShaneQful It was amazing