# How can I convert a string from underscore or dashed format to camelCase or UpperCamelCase in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, camelcasing

How can I take a string that is in dashed notation :

`something-like-this`

or underscore notation :

`something_like_this`

and convert it to camelCase :

`somethingLikeThis`

or UpperCamelCase :

`SomethingLikeThis`

?

**Edited to add** @torazaburo accuses this of being a duplicate of [Converting any string into camel case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970525/converting-any-string-into-camel-case) however, that question does not address either of the inputs, dashed or underscore, in question here.  @torazaburo, please revoke your false accusation.

Answer (score 4):

For those who'd rather not mess with natives :

```
toCamelCase = function(string){
    return string.replace(/[_\-]([^_\-])/g, function($0,$1){return $1.toUpperCase();});
}
toUpperCamelCase = function(string){
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + toCamelCase(string.substring(1));
}
```

Or for those comfortable extending natives:

```
if (!String.prototype.toCamelCase)String.prototype.toCamelCase = function(){
    return this.replace(/[_\-]([^_\-])/g, function($0,$1){return $1.toUpperCase();});
};
if (!String.prototype.toUpperCamelCase)String.prototype.toUpperCamelCase = function(){
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.substring(1).toCamelCase();
};
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/akj0hx7b/

Answer (score 1):

trex005's answer is good enough, but mine takes input in dashed, underscore, camelCase OR UpperCamelCase.  Not sure you've converted a string yet? Convert it again! No worries!

For those who'd rather not mess with natives:

```
toCamelCase = function(string){
    string = string.replace(/[_\-A-Z]([^_\-A-Z])/g, function($0,$1){return $0.charAt(0).match(/[A-Z]/)?$0:$1.toUpperCase();});
    return string.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + string.substring(1);
}
toUpperCamelCase = function(string){
    string = toCamelCase(string);
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.substring(1);
}
```

Or for those comfortable extending natives

```
if (!String.prototype.toCamelCase)String.prototype.toCamelCase = function(){
    string = this.replace(/[_\-A-Z]([^_\-A-Z])/g, function($0,$1){return $0.charAt(0).match(/[A-Z]/)?$0:$1.toUpperCase();});
    return string.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + string.substring(1);
}
if (!String.prototype.toUpperCamelCase)String.prototype.toUpperCamelCase = function(){
    string = toCamelCase(this);
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.substring(1);
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/akj0hx7b/1/

Answer (score 1):

[trex005's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32392146/482197) was good, and [trex005's addition to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32392822/482197) was even more handy, but if you're going to go that far, why not go all the way and allow you to convert back and forth between dashed, underscore, camelCase AND UpperCamelCase as needed?

For those who'd rather not mess with natives:

```
formatParts = function(string){
    var parts = [];
    string.replace(/([_\-A-Z]|^[^_\-A-Z])([^_\-A-Z]*)/g,function($0,$1,$2){
        var part = $1.match(/[_\-]/)?$2:$1+$2;
        parts.push(part.toLowerCase());
    });
    return parts;
}
toCamelCase = function(string){
    var output = '';
    formatParts(string).forEach(function(part,index){
        output += index?part.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part.substring(1):part;
    });
    return output;
}
toUpperCamelCase = function(string){
    var output = '';
    formatParts(string).forEach(function(part,index){
        output += part.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part.substring(1);
    });
    return output;
}
toDashed = function(string){
    return formatParts(string).join('-');
}
toUnderscored = function(string){
    return formatParts(string).join('_');
}
```

Or for those comfortable extending natives:

```
if (!String.prototype.formatParts)String.prototype.formatParts = function(){
    var parts = [];
    this.replace(/([_\-A-Z]|^[^_\-A-Z])([^_\-A-Z]*)/g,function($0,$1,$2){
        var part = $1.match(/[_\-]/)?$2:$1+$2;
        parts.push(part.toLowerCase());
    });
    return parts;
}
if (!String.prototype.toCamelCase)String.prototype.toCamelCase = function(){
    var output = '';
    this.formatParts().forEach(function(part,index){
        output += index?part.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part.substring(1):part;
    });
    return output;
}
if (!String.prototype.toUpperCamelCase)String.prototype.toUpperCamelCase = function(){
    var output = '';
    this.formatParts().forEach(function(part,index){
        output += part.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part.substring(1);
    });
    return output;
}
if (!String.prototype.toDashed)String.prototype.toDashed = function(){
    return this.formatParts().join('-');
}
if (!String.prototype.toUnderscored)String.prototype.toUnderscored = function(){
    return this.formatParts().join('_');
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/akj0hx7b/3/