# How do I add two CSS rules to one html element

Tags: html, css, angular2-template

```
 <p class="smallText">{{vehicleItem.registration}}, {{vehicleItem.colour}} {{vehicleItem.make}} {{vehicleItem.model}}</p>
```

I'd like to capitalize vehicle registration and model and make should be camel case

Comment: Please see how to ask a question to ensure you can get an appropriate response: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have edited the question @BobbySpeirs

Comment: provide your  code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest wrapping registration and make with a span containing different classes e.g.

```
<p><span class="capitalize">{{vehicleItem.registration}}, {{vehicleItem.colour}} <span class="camel-case">{{vehicleItem.make}} </span> {{vehicleItem.model}}</p>
```

This way you are adding "two" css rules to one element. I also recommend you achieve the camelcase style using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can write as many classes into an HTML tag as you want, thereby applying as many CSS rules as you want. Example:

```
<p class="smallText myclass_1 myclass_2">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced with angular but you should be able to use different functions like

```
capitalizeFirstLetter(vehicleItem.registration)
```

and
    camelize(vehicleItem.model)

[Converting any string into camel case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970525/converting-any-string-into-camel-case)

[How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)