# regex camelize particular text inside string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have a next string:

```
  $scope.string = "User {{User Firstname}} </p><p>System {{Reported System Name}} </p><p>Desc {{Description}}</p><ol></ol>"
```

I'm trying to achieve next result:

```
 $scope.string = "User {{userFirstname}} </p><p>System {{reportedSystemName}} </p><p>Desc {{description}}</p><ol></ol>"
```

With help of regex I can find necessary for camelize text

```
if ($scope.string.match(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g)){
       for (var i = 0; i < $scope.string.match(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g).length; i ++){
             $scope.string.match(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g)[i] = camelizeBrackets($scope.string.match(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g)[i])
        }
  }
```

But the function `camelizeBrackets` which I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2970667/6524629) and modified to work with text inside curly braces doesn't work at all

```
 function camelizeBrackets(str) {
     return str.replace(/\{\{(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w|\s+)\}\}/g, function(match, index) {
        if (+match === 0) return "";
          return index === 0 ? match.toLowerCase() : match.toUpperCase();
       });
   }
```

Could anybody explain me what I'm doing wrong?

[My plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nIqtn9RbR0RJuRmkvjUO?p=preview)

Comment: To explain what you're doing wrong requires an explanation of what you're trying to do _or_ a regex of what you're trying to do. This part of the regex `(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w|\s+)` can't explain anything because it's un-discernible. So, got a better explanation ?

Comment: @sln I updated my question, let me know if you need additional explanation

Comment: So you're trying to remove whitespace, tolower the first letter of the first word, toupper the second, third,.. word letters ? What about the letters after the first letter, tolower them ?

Comment: String.match returns an array of matches, but setting an element of that array to something new will not affect the original string.  You will want to do  $scope.string = $scope.string.replace(*some regex*, *some replacement function*);  See [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in 2 steps, get the inner brackets contents, then camelize that.

(Note - you can replace the *not-word* `\W` with a whitespace `\s` if you only
want to delete whitespace)

Explained

```
    ^ \W* 
    ( \w )                        # (1), First letter of first word
 |                          # or,
    \b 
    ( \w )                        # (2), First letter of other words
 |                          # or,  
    ( \W )                        # (3), Non-words, whitespace, etc...
```

```js
function camelize(str)
{
   return str.replace( /^\W*(\w)|\b(\w)|(\W)/g,
      function(match, g1,g2,g3) {
          if ( g1 != null )    // first word, first letter
             return g1.toLowerCase();
          else
          if ( g2 != null )    // second word's, first letter
             return g2.toUpperCase();

          return '';           // all non-word letters( wsp )
      }
   )
}

function camelizeBrackets(str)
{
   return str.replace(/\{\{([\S\s]*?)\}\}/g,
      function(match, g1) {
         return '{{' + camelize( g1 ) + '}}';
        }
      );
} 

console.log( camelizeBrackets("{{EquipmentClass name}}") );
console.log( camelizeBrackets("{{Equipment className}}") );
console.log( camelizeBrackets("{{equipment class name}}") );
console.log( camelizeBrackets("{{Equipment Class Name}}") );

console.log( camelizeBrackets("User {{User Firstname}} </p><p>System {{Reported System Name}} </p><p>Desc {{Description}}</p><ol></ol>") );
```

All output `{{equipmentClassName}}`

with
`User {{userFirstname}} </p><p>System {{reportedSystemName}} </p><p>Desc {{description}}</p><ol></ol>`
at the end.