# How to use the prototype functions in predefined global variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Please tell me how can I use the injected functions in predefined variables. Here's the script to convert a string into camel case, but I don't know how to use it.

```
String.prototype.toCamelCase = function(str) {
    return str
        .replace(/\s(.)/g, function($1) { return $1.toUpperCase(); })
        .replace(/\s/g, '')
        .replace(/^(.)/, function($1) { return $1.toLowerCase(); });
}
```

Also, tell me if there is any relevancy of using `$1` as the arguments! I mean is there any use of `$` in this function?

P.S. I took this script from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970525/converting-any-string-into-camel-case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, tell me if there is any relevancy of using `$1` as the arguments! I mean is there any use of `$` in this function?

No, it's just the param's name.

> Please tell me how can I use the injected functions in predefined variables. Here's the script to convert a string into camel case, but I don't know how to use it.

- You only need to instantiate variables of that type (string).
- The prototype is useful when you need to operate over the specific object, so you don't need to pass a string, rather, use the current context `this`, in this case, a string.

```js
String.prototype.toCamelCase = function() {
    return this // Here you use the current object using the context 'this'
        .replace(/\s(.)/g, function($1) { return $1.toUpperCase(); })
        .replace(/\s/g, '')
        .replace(/^(.)/, function($1) { return $1.toLowerCase(); });
}

console.log("ele from so".toCamelCase());
```