# how to convert passed string to Camel Case

Tags: javascript, string

Hi I'm working on a problem that requires me to 'returns the passed string convertedToCamelCase'

I tried doing it like this

```
let wordsArr = words.toLowerCase().split(" ")
  for (let i = 1; i<wordsArr.length; i++){
  wordsArr[i] = wordsArr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()
  wordsArr.slice(1)
  }
  return wordsArr.join("")
```

but that doesnt seem to work and now im stuck

Comment: Hello. Did you look here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970525/converting-any-string-into-camel-case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting any string into camel case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970525/converting-any-string-into-camel-case)

Comment: I think you should use a dictionary with predefined words to achieve that, cause there is no way you can detect end of words without knowing them in advance

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work if it doesn't contain punctuation

```js
let camelot = "I have to push the pram a lot";
const makeCamel = s => {
  let camelArray = s.toLowerCase().split(' ')
  let newArray = [camelArray[0]]
  for (let i in camelArray) {
    if (i >= 1) {
      let capLetter = camelArray[i][0].toUpperCase()
      let rest = camelArray[i].slice(1);
      let newWord = capLetter + rest
      newArray.push(newWord);
      
    }
  }
  return newArray.join('');

}
makeCamel(camelot)
```